# How to send parameters to PHP script from VBA

Tags: php, vba, ms-access, xmlhttprequest

I need to send a POST request from an MS Access VBA script to a remote PHP script to return database data. The VBA script works fine but I can't send a required parameter.

VBA

```
Set oXHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP.6.0")
oXHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
oXHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/json"
oXHTTP.send "getorglist=true"
doCURL = oXHTTP.responseText
```

PHP

```
if(filter_has_var(INPUT_POST, 'getorglist'))   {
  echo json_encode(getOrgList($pdo));       
  return;
}
```

The VBA script works, returns a 200 response, but empty data. If I remove all but the middle line of the PHP script the correct JSON code is returned.

What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some online searches and experiments, I find that the solution is to replace line 3 in the VBA code (the `setRequestHeader` line) with:

```
oXHTTP.setRequestHeader "Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"
```

This works, but I can't see why, which is troubling. Can somebody advise?